# Identifying rows of a parameter sweep run in LTspice raw results

Tags: ltspice

I want to use a parameter sweep with transient analysis and parse the output results. Unfortunately, I cannot identify where the results from one parameter sweep ends and the other starts in the raw output results.

```
1967        2.563416514428829e+000
    2.400000000000000e+001
    4.493277543997481e-004
    -1.061473136170760e-003
1968        2.572499072839490e+000
    2.400000000000000e+001
    1.122131554555143e-003
    -1.061432747027046e-003
```

point 1968 should be from the next run, but how can I identify that from the output? Just guessing the number of points in a run (TotalPoints/NumOfRuns) also does not seem to work properly. There is some information in the .log file, but I am not sure how to use it.

Even if I identify the correct points from the different runs, can I trust that the previous run does not affect the next one?

Comment: Does the spacing look like it does here? Does it use tabs or spaces? Maybe run number is the only field at the beginning of a line without space?

Comment: Distinguisting between integers and reals will probably tell you.

Comment: @Justin Yes, this is the spacing. It uses two tabs after the point index and one on each subsequent line. There is no way to distinguish a new run just by looking at the points data.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, how exactly?

Comment: Where did you get this from? What is the error log showing you that you don't understand?

Comment: Do new runs restart the point index from 0?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen It's a poorly written question.  That's from the `.raw` file when running LTspice with the `-ascii` command-line switch.  Let's say you have one param that's stepped to 3 different values, and it shows `tranpoints = 1000` in the error log.  Then it will show 3000 different time points in that `.raw` file and he's asking if there's a way to know how to identify each chunk of 1000 points corresponding to each step.  It's trivial in my example but consider many more params and many more steps.  I do not know the answer.

Comment: Maybe he should be using `.meas` statements instead???

Comment: @SteKulov OP can use the hammer for all I care, but `-ascii`? *shudders* Not while there's `ltsputil.exe`, or simply the builtin export.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  I think you are under the wrong impression that I am an expert in using LTspice, it is exactly the opposite. Thank you for the idea of using ltsputil.exe, is it also available for LTspiceXVII? I want to do everything from the cli, if you know any other method I will be grateful to know.

Comment: @SteKulov, I will have probably multiple step conditions, and as I mentioned, I don't know how to use the information from the .log file. Do you know of some manual which describes what the different values there mean? In my tests the number of total points does not divide exactly on the tranpoints count

Comment: @djvuk  The top of the `.raw` file gives you a legend of what each line for each timepoint means.  The first value (the value on the same line as the timepoint index) is always time itself, so I think each point where time reverts back to zero is when the program assumes that it jumps to the next evaluated `.step`.  These `.step`s are listed line-by-line in the error log and I assume it uses that same order found there when it jumps between them.

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks, that's awesome! I don't know how I have missed this. That's the answer